# Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("sweetalert2")' has no compatible call signatures

Tags: angular, sweetalert2

I am getting "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("sweetalert2")' has no compatible call signatures." this error while using SWAL in angular.

### My package-cli.json looks like

```
    "ng2-sweetalert2": {
    "version": "0.0.8",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ng2-sweetalert2/-/ng2-sweetalert2-0.0.8.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha1-+VkDV2dqeLIMf3eFTLVt/cJda0Q=",
    "requires": {
        "lodash.assign": "^4.0.8",
        "sweetalert2": "^5.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "es6-promise": {
            "version": "4.2.6",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/es6-promise/-/es6-promise-4.2.6.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha512-aRVgGdnmW2OiySVPUC9e6m+plolMAJKjZnQlCwNSuK5yQ0JN61DZSO1X1Ufd1foqWRAlig0rhduTCHe7sVtK5Q=="
        },
        "sweetalert2": {
            "version": "5.3.8",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sweetalert2/-/sweetalert2-5.3.8.tgz",
            "integrity": "sha1-YALBhFPQYMQLnMVL+DoBDHHjlik=",
            "requires": {
                "es6-promise": "^4.2.6"
            }
        }
    }
}

"sweetalert2": {
      "version": "8.9.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sweetalert2/-/sweetalert2-8.9.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-gI+wL44QRbfd6FvRVB8KKLQPhD/8jP3XUNrvYGcSlU7IA09dQtQw3rrLCbM3c+HY0L3O8VTz1Gvu29n8ryIgag=="
}
```

### and I have following things in package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies":{
"ng2-sweetalert2": "0.0.8",
"sweetalert2": "^8.9.0",}
```

In a component my code is like below

```
import * as swal from 'sweetalert2';

        swal({
          text: 'Login Successful!',
          timer: 1000,
          onOpen: () => {
            swal.showLoading()
          }
        })then((result) => {
          if (result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer) {
              // calling few required functions here
          }
        })
```

In the component I am getting the above mentioned error. Searched a lot but couldn't figure out the problem. please help me.

Comment: You certainly miss a `.` before your `then` call. However I don't think that is your problem. Do you have the line where the error occurs? Also, you installed _ng2-sweetalert2_, but you are using only sweetalert2. Can you try using it [this way](https://github.com/seiyria/ng2-sweetalert2)?

Comment: Yes I missed that dot. Even after using it  I am receiving the same error. I used npm install --save sweetlaert2.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue.Use

```
swal.fire()
```

instead of

```
swal()
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You installed two dependencies via *package.json*:

- `sweetalert2`, which is a pure(!) javascript library. It has nothing to do with angular.
- `ng2-sweetalert2`, which is an Angular service, which wraps the native `sweetalert2` library into an Angular service. According to the [GitHub page](https://github.com/seiyria/ng2-sweetalert2), this is deprecated.

I recommend removing `sweetalert2` and from your *package.json*, and add [ngx-sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2):

```
npm install --save sweetalert2 @sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2
```

Set up the module described in [ngx-sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2), from there, you have multiple ways to make it work, via directive or component.